# filter on sheet1 also filters sheet2 based on sheet1 filtered values

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have multiple sheets in a excel file and the Address sheet contains the columns: Postal Code, House, City and Employee sheet contains the columns: Name, Contact, House, Postal Code. I wish to filter my sheets so that I can find the employees from a particular City.

Address Sheet:

| Postal Code | House | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EC1V 9LT | 372 Old Street | London |
| NW3 6BT | 176 Finchley Road | London |
| M14 5TD | 6 Wilmslow Road, Rusholme | Manchester |
| YO1 9RA | 7-9 Clifford Street | York |

Employee Sheet:

| Name | Contact | House | Postal Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | XXXXX-XXXXXX | 372 Old Street | EC1V 9LT |
| Employee 2 | XXXXX-XXXXXX | 176 Finchley Road | NW3 6BT |
| Employee 3 | XXXXX-XXXXXX | 6 Wilmslow Road, Rusholme | M14 5TD |
| Employee 4 | XXXXX-XXXXXX | 7-9 Clifford Street | YO1 9RA |

Filtered Address Sheet:

| Postal Code | House | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EC1V 9LT | 372 Old Street | London |
| NW3 6BT | 176 Finchley Road | London |

Which will automatically filter the Employee Sheet also giving the below result:

| Name | Contact | House | Postal Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | XXXXX-XXXXXX | 372 Old Street | EC1V 9LT |
| Employee 2 | XXXXX-XXXXXX | 176 Finchley Road | NW3 6BT |

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to add a City column on the Employee Sheet by using vlookup function, so you will have everything on 1 sheet. For this you will need to create a new column Key on each sheet, where will be concatenated values from columns House and Postal Code. It will be something like this:

Address Sheet:

[image]

Employee Sheet:

[image]

where vlookup function in City column will look something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2;Address_Sheet_Name!C:D;2;0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is it possible to do it without adding columns to the Employee sheet?